# The inverse of some matrices are different between Python and Excel. Which results I should consider?

Tags: python, excel, matrix, inverse

I tested two 3x3 matrix to know the inverse in Python and Excel, but the results are different. Which I should consider as the correct or best result?

These are the matrix I tested:

Matrix 1:

```
1 0 0 
1 2 0
1 2 3
```

Matrix 2:

```
1 0 0 
4 5 0 
7 8 9
```

The Matrix 1 inverse is the same in Python and Excel, but Matrix 2 inverse is different.

In Excel I use the **MINVERSE(*matrix*)** function, and in Python **np.linalg.inv(*matrix*)** (from Numpy library) 
I can't post images yet, so I can't show the results from Excel :c 
This is the code I use in Python:

```
# Matrix 1
A = np.array([[1,0,0],
             [1,2,0],
             [1,2,3]])
Ainv = np.linalg.inv(A)
print(Ainv)

Result:
[[ 1.          0.          0.        ]
 [-0.5         0.5         0.        ]
 [ 0.         -0.33333333  0.33333333]]

# (This is the same in Excel)
```

```
# Matrix 2
B = np.array([[1,0,0],
             [4,5,0],
             [7,8,9]])
Binv = np.linalg.inv(B)
print(Binv)

Result:
[[ 1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -6.16790569e-18]
 [-8.00000000e-01  2.00000000e-01  1.23358114e-17]
 [-6.66666667e-02 -1.77777778e-01  1.11111111e-01]]

# (This is different in Excel)
```

Comment: Seems like a question of precision. The two different elements are basically 0... https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gLtW.png

Comment: Right.  Those two matrices are equal, within the limits of floating point math.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I did not notice at all that those numbers are so small that they must be considered 0.

Comment: I wanted to upvote both answers, but I don't have enough reputation yet :c